# Expired UK work Visa (Sole Rep) returning for 3 days

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I had a Sole Rep work visa in the UK that expired about 6 months ago.  I have been back in the US for about a year or so.   I need to return to UK for a couple days as tourist.   Will this be an issue?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Not really a problem, people do that all the time. Carry some stuff to show you have an economic base in the US and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

No, why would it?

You had a visa that expired.  You left the country before your visa expired.  You now wish to travel to the country for a different purpose.  You will get a new visa for that purpose (unless you are exempt from a visa requirement, for example, by being a US citizen).  Surely this happens all the time.

If you overstayed your welcome in the past, or if you were removed from the country by immigration authorities or whoever does that, then you would have a problem.  From the fact that you did not mention this in your question, I assume that nothing like this is the case.